# Numerical calculation of Fourier transform with a nice error bound

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, integration

I'd like to have an algorithm for a numerical calculation of Fourier transform with a nice error bound. To be precise, if $f$ is a function from $L_1(R)$, $F[f]$ is it's exact Fourier transform and  $F_a[f]$ is the "numerical" Fourier transform, I'd like to have the 
inequality 
$$
\int_{R} Err(x) dx < \infty, 
$$ 
where $Err(x):=|F[f](x) - F_a[f](x)|$, 
or at least 
$$
 Err(x) < G(x),  
$$
where $G(x) \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$. 
Do such algorithms exist (at least for functions $f$ from some narrow classes)?
Or maybe someone may give concrete examples of algorithms and functions $f$ for which the error $Err(x)$ tends to zero as $|x| \to \infty$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a subject of [a very nice paper by Charlie Epstein (2004)](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~cle/papers/fftvsft.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

If a numerical algorithm is only allowed to evaluate $f$ at a finite set of points, you're going to have a problem: $f$ might happen to be $0$ at all the 
points where you evaluate it.  Clearly no error bound is possible under such circumstances.